# Angular 14 - How to break two way binding on formgroups inside formarray for mat-dialog?

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-formbuilder, mat-dialog

**My problem is detailed lower down.** I have a mat-dialog that is used to edit a previous data entry. Each entry has a FormGroup in the form of a Deliverable. So a FormControl name, and a FormArray Steps. Then the FormArray Steps has a FormGroup with two FormControls. Something like this:

```
// TOTALLY PSEUDO
Deliverable = FormGroup({
  name: FormControl,
  steps: FormArray[FormGroup({
    step_num: FormControl,
    step_name: FormControl
  }), FormGroup({
    step_num: FormControl,
    step_name: FormControl
  })]
})
```

Edit function:

```
export interface Deliverable {
  name: string,
  steps: any[]
}

edit(deliverable: Deliverable) {
  const tempSteps = Object.assign([], deliverable.steps)
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeliverableDialogComponent, {
    data: { name: deliverable.name, steps: tempSteps }
  })

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
}
```

On the DeliverableDialogComponent.html:

```
<mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Deliverable Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="data.name" />
    </mat-form-field>
    <div *ngFor="let step of data.steps; let stepIndex=index">
        <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Step Number</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="text" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="step.step_num">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Step Name</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="text" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="step.step_name">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

On the DeliverableDialogComponent.ts:

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

export interface Deliverable {
  name: string;
  steps: any[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-deliverable-dialog',
  templateUrl: './deliverable-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deliverable-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class DeliverableDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DeliverableDialogComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Deliverable) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close()
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

**My problem is that there is a two way connection for the steps, both step_num and step_name.** So when I make a change in the dialog, it is updating the step_num and step_name on the original component. I don't want this functionality as I only want it to update when I click save, and to not update when I hit cancel or just click out of the dialog. The Deliverable.name works fine, but the steps are two way binded.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by making a deepcopy of deliverable.steps by using this:

```
const tempSteps = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(deliverable.steps))

//INSTEAD OF

const tempSteps = Object.assign([], deliverable.steps)
```